# Having Troubles Posting a list of names from a database using ASP wanting to create a Hierarchy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp-classic

This code is finding a list of names from a database and using  tag to post them on the website the select tag is modified so it just looks like a list. This works pretty good however on mobile it is literally a drop down bar.

**Any suggestions on how to make it look good on mobile?**

```
            <div class="row"> 
                    <div class"col-md-12 align="center"><h1><strong>Employee Hierarchy</strong><h1></div> 
            </div>

            <div class="row"> 
                    <div class"col-md-12 align="center">To View Hierarch for Printing Click <a href=<% = fileUrl %> ><button>Here</button></a></div> 
            </div>

            <br>
            <div class="row"> 
                    <div class"col-md-12 align="center"><p>Click on Employee to View Phone Number</p></div> 
            </div>

            <div class="row>
                <div class="col-md-12 align="center">
                    <div class"form-group">

                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="phones.asp" method ="Post" id = "frm">
                        <select class="selectpicker;.input-group-lg&gt;.form-control,select.input-group-lg&gt;.input-group-addon,select.input-group-lg&gt;.input-group-btn&gt;.btn" size=29 width=100% name="query" onchange="this.form.submit()" ID=listOrgChart>

<%
    conn = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=trlsqlp05;DATABASE=Cominco;UID=phonesapp;PWD=!Phones;AutoTimeout=    No;Connect Timeout=5"
    SQL = "exec generateorgchart " + abnum
    set recs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    recs.Open SQL,conn
    if( recs.EOF) then
    %>

    <%
    else
    set fsoorg = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set fsofile = fsoorg.OpenTextFile(enter code here file, 2, True)
    While (not recs.EOF)
        oname = recs.Fields.Item("descrip")
        tname = replace(trim(recs.Fields.Item("surname")),"""","'")
%>
        <OPTION VALUE=<% = tname %> ><% = oname %></OPTION>
<%
        oname = replace(oname,"&nbsp"," ")
        fsofile.WriteLine oname
        recs.MoveNext
    WEND
    fsofile.close
    set fsofile = Nothing
    set fsoorg = Nothing
    end if
    recs.close
    set recs = Nothing
    %>
enter code here

</SELECT></form></div></div>
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're working in classic-asp? Is this brownfield work or a new project? Also, with your bootstrap tags, if you only declare col-md-12 it doesn't address small and extra small devices, just FYI.

Comment: Yawn... Not another lecture on why people shouldn't be using Classic ASP!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how your code looks on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/T4b9le9pPQ) - you seem to have a lot of unclosed quotes for your classes and other problems that is causing a few issues.

Here's a [cleaned up version](http://www.bootply.com/H7aMkm7Use) (with your Classic ASP script removed as it is not relevant to your Bootstrap issues):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
            <div class"col-xs-12">
            <h1>Employee Hierarchy</h1>
            <p>To View Hierarch for Printing Click <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Here</a></p>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="phones.asp" method="Post" id="frm">
                <div class"form-group">
                    <label for="listOrgChart">Click on Employee to View Phone Number</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="query" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="listOrgChart">

                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```